# Sum of squares in an array using function

Tags: java, arrays, function

Question :
 Write a program that allows the entry of an integer value n, followed by two sets of n integer values into arrays A and B. The program should use a function to calculate the sum of the square of corresponding values of A and B. These values should then be displayed.

My piece of code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question9_SumOfSquareInArrays {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int sumA = 0;
         int sumB = 0;
         int n;
         int i=0;


         Scanner src=new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Please enter value :");
         n=src.nextInt();

         int [] A=new int[n];
         int [] B=new int[n];

         System.out.println("Enter value for array A :");
         for(i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
            A[i]=src.nextInt();
         }
         System.out.println("Enter value for array B :");

         for(i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
             B[i]=src.nextInt();
         }
         src.close();

        System.out.println("Total sum for array A is " + SumOfA(sumA));
         System.out.println("Total sum for array B is " + sumOfB(sumB));




    }

    public static int SumOfA(int sumA)
    {
        int square=1;
        int sum=0;   
        int n=6;
       int [] A= new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            square=A[i]*A[i];
            sum+=square;
        }
        return sum;

    }

    public static int sumOfB(int sumB)
    {
        int square=1;
        int n=6;
        int sum=0;
        int [] B=new int [n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            square=B[i]*B[i];
            sum+=square;

        }
        return sum;

}
}
```

I am not able to find out my mistakes. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Your question is likely to get closed unless you give some more information. Specifically, what output are you expecting, and what output are you getting?

Comment: no error from compiler?

Comment: I think you misread the assignment. You are supposed to calculate the sums of the squares of corresponding elements in the array. So this would mean Aᵢ² + Bᵢ².

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int SumOfA(int sumA)
{
    int square=1;
    int sum=0;   
    int n=6;
   int [] A= new int[n]; // you are calculating the sum of this array
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        square=A[i]*A[i];
        sum+=square;
    }
    return sum;
```

}

is problematic because it calculates the sum of an array of `0`s.

Instead, you need to pass your array to the method, i.e.

in `main` you need

```
System.out.println("Total sum for array A is " + SumOfA(A));
```

and modify your `SumOfA` as follows. Notice it's better to use `n = A.length` since the length of `A` is not necessarily always 6.

```
public static int SumOfA(int[] A)
{
    int square=1;
    int sum=0;   
    int n=A.length; // use length to handle array A of any length

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        square=A[i]*A[i];
        sum+=square;
    }
    return sum;

}
```

The other method has the same problem

Comment: Thank you but I still get some errors in the methods for the part :square=A[i]*A[i];

Comment: @Umme Not knowing what error you are getting it's difficult to fix them. I guess your problem is that the array `A` has less than 6 elements, and edited my program. Maybe this helps.